# How do I solve this axis error that occurs whenever I try to find the mean RGB values of multiple images

Tags: python, numpy

I've been creating a program that will return the mean RGB values of all of the images stored in a folder as a list.

I've already written the code to find the mean RGB values of a single image as shown below.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
myimg2 = cv2.imread('/Users/farzeent.farooqui/Desktop/colors.jpg') 
avg_color = np.array(myimg2).mean(axis=(0,1))
avg_rgb = avg_color[::-1]
print(avg_rgb)
```

I then used a for loop to get the RGB values for all of the images

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np
import os                      

def test():
    path_of_images = "/Users/farzeent.farooqui/Frames"
    list_of_images = os.listdir(path_of_images)

    for image in list_of_images:

        myimg2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_of_images, image) )
        avg_color = np.array(myimg2).mean(axis=(0,1))
        avg_rgb = avg_color[::-1]
        print(avg_rgb)
test()
```

But when I try to run the program I keep getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-fbd55f77ab7c> in <module>
----> 1 test()

 <ipython-input-123-ed7d4e9de700> in test()
     10 
     11         myimg2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_of_images, image) )
 ---> 12         avg_color = np.array(myimg2).mean(axis=(0,1))
     13         avg_rgb = avg_color[::-1]
 14         print(avg_rgb)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _mean(a,         axis, dtype, out, keepdims, where)
    164     is_float16_result = False
    165 
--> 166     rcount = _count_reduce_items(arr, axis, keepdims=keepdims, where=where)
    167     if rcount == 0 if where is True else umr_any(rcount == 0):
    168         warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in    _count_reduce_items(arr, axis, keepdims, where)
    73         items = nt.intp(1)
    74         for ax in axis:
---> 75             items *= arr.shape[mu.normalize_axis_index(ax, arr.ndim)]
    76     else:
    77         # TODO: Optimize case when `where` is broadcast along a non-reduction

AxisError: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

Comment: `os.listdir` will give you all the files in the directory, not just images. you may want to print your numpy array and it's contents/shape to see what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @burglarhobbit pointed out in the comments your directory likely contains non-image files, which is causing your code to throw an error.

The piece of code below will help you find files in a specific directory that have known image file extensions.

```
from os import path, walk

def get_image_files(directory_of_images):
    """
     This function is designed to traverse a directory tree and extract all
     the image names contained in the directory.
    :param directory_of_images: the name of the target directory containing
           the images to be trained on.
    :return: list of images to be processed.
    """
    images_to_process = []
    accepted_extensions = ('.bmp', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.svg', '.tiff')
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(directory_of_images):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(accepted_extensions):
                images_to_process.append(path.join(dirpath, filename))
        return images_to_process


list_of_images = get_image_files('/Users/user_name/Python_Projects/scratch_pad')
for image_to_process in list_of_images:
    myimg2 = cv2.imread(image_to_process)
    avg_color = np.array(myimg2).mean(axis=(0, 1))
    avg_rgb = avg_color[::-1]
    print(avg_rgb)
    # output
    [239.08779842 239.08779842 239.08779842]
    [186.64632099 163.64886914 150.54838519]
```

Comment: IMHO, it's better to put invariant stuff, like your `accepted_extensions`, **outside** of loops rather than recreating it for every file in every directory when it doesn't change.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I hadn't considered that thanks for the tip.  I have modified my function accordingly.